# SQL Connections and transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, database-connection

Do you have to keep a (the same) SQL connection open for the duration of a transaction, and do you have to call CommitTransaction and RollbackTransaction on the same connection that called BeginTransaction.

We have a database helper class with methods to begin- commit- and rollbacktransactions, as well as the usual select, execute stored proc, etc.

The helper class looks more or less like this:

```
public class DatabaseHelper
{
    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
         // open connection, but dont close it.
    }

    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
         // close the connection
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
         // close the connection
    }
```

So because of this we can NOT do the usual (which I would've preferred) such as this:

```
using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // sql operations here
}
```

The helper class currently leaves the connection open as long as there is an existing transaction and closes it during commit or rollback. However it got me wondering if that is really the best way to do it? Does the connection have to stay open for the duration of the transaction?

Comment: how can you work with that helper? BeginTransaction should at minimum return the transaction that you will then pass back to the Commit method!

Comment: Yes, I don't like it either, but I am fixing existing production code that was written by someone else, so want to cause as little as possible changes to what is already tested and "working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will have to stay open. You can handle the OnDispose of your class and Dispose of the connection in that.

```
public class DatabaseHelper : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //close/dispose connection here
    }
}
```

Then you could do...

```
using(DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper())
{
}
```

Comment: @Ghlouw : If you implement what musefan suggests, in your Dispose you could also check if the connection is still open, and if so, commit your changes should you want to. Or, if you want, you can explicitly rollback, but as Ben Robinson stated, if your SQL session terminates with a pending change, it will automatically be rolledback.

Comment: @Tipx, I think the default on dispose should be to rollback if there are still transactions pending. It would be bad to assume a commit as default in the event an error occurs and more so that the developer has not explicitly called for the commit

Comment: I think so too, but I just point out that he could, should he want to!

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure transaction are rolled back automatically if the connection is closed before committing. Your helper class does not have to create and dispose of the connection to manage the transactions and opening and closing of the connection, just have it take a connection parameter in a constructor, then you can use your usual using syntax.

e.g.:

```
using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(sqlCon);
    helper.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        //Sql stuff
        helper.CommitTransaction();
    }
    catch(SqlException)
    {
         helper.RollbackTransaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: They are rollbacked, but if you want to check for yourself, you can break into the code once your transaction is started, and locked a table, check with an SQL client if the table is locked. If so, just STOP the debugger, then confirm that the table not locked anymore.